# There's a lot of unwanted space between my tables

Tags: tables, spacing

I'm new to making tables and I'm having a problem with the space between them.

```
 \begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Conferências, revistas e periódicos da IEEE de interesse}
  \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.25\textwidth}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.75\textwidth}}
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}\textbf{Acrônimos} & \textbf{Nome completo}\\
    \rowcolor{white}TrustCom & 2018 17th IEEE International Conference On Trust, Security And Privacy In Computing And Communications \\
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}BigDataSE & 12th IEEE International Conference On Big Data Science And Engineering\\
    \rowcolor{white}ICCCS & 2019 4th International Conference on Computing, Communications and Security \\
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}ATS & 2019 IEEE 28th Asian Test Symposium \\
    \rowcolor{white}MSR & 2019 IEEE/ACM 16th International Conference on Mining Software Repositories \\
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}ICOIN & 2019 International Conference on Information Networking \\
    \rowcolor{white}ISVLSI & 2020 IEEE Computer Society Annual Symposium on VLSI \\
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}ICAC & 2021 26th International Conference on Automation and Computing \\
    \rowcolor{white}INCET & 2021 2nd International Conference for Emerging  Technology \\
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}ICACCS & 2021 7th International Conference on Advanced Computing and Communication Systems \\
    \rowcolor{white}Big Data & 2021 IEEE International Conference on Big Data \\
   \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}ASIANCON & 2022 2nd Asian Conference on Innovation in Technology \\
    \rowcolor{white}NCCC & 2022 Fifth National Conference of Saudi Computers Colleges \\
   \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}CCNC & 2022 IEEE 19th Annual Consumer Communications \& Networking Conference \\
    \rowcolor{white}TrustCom & 2022 IEEE International Conference on Trust, Security and Privacy in Computing and Communications \\
   \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}DISCOVER & 2022 International Conference on Distributed Computing, VLSI, Electrical Circuits and Robotics \\
    \rowcolor{white}ICIMCIS & 2022 International Conference on Informatics, Multimedia, Cyber and Information System \\
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}MLCSS & 2022 International Conference on Machine Learning, Computer Systems and Security \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Tabela de Critérios de Inclusão e Exclusão}
  \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.3\textwidth}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.7\textwidth}}
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}\textbf{Critérios de Inclusão} &\\
    \rowcolor{white}IC1 & O artigo foi publicado entre 2018-2022 \\
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}IC2 & O artigo está no contexto de Vírus de computador e propõe uma abordagem para análise e detecção do vírus\\
    \rowcolor{white}\textbf{Critérios de Exclusão} & \\
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}EC1 & O artigo não foi publicado em uma conferência, periódico ou revista listados na Tabela 1 e 2 \\
    \rowcolor{white}EC2 & O manuscrito é um livro ou artigo de acesso antecipado\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

That's my code but when I compile there's a big space between the tables:
[image: big space]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it is impossible to  say from the fragment posted, please show a small complete document.  If 2 tables do not fit on a page,what you show is expected, until you add more text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A said @David Carlisle, positioning of your tables is expected.

Both floats will be pushed to top of pages if you will add some text after second table and change ratio between spaces for text and floats on pages. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{.05}     % <---
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{.9} % <---

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Conferências, revistas e periódicos da IEEE de interesse}
\begin{tblr}{colspec  = {Q[l, wd=0.2\linewidth] X[l]},
             row{odd} = {bg=gray!10},
             row{1}   = {font=\bfseries}
             }
Acrônimos   &   Nome completo       \\
TrustCom    & 2018 17th IEEE International Conference On Trust, Security And Privacy In Computing And Communications \\
BigDataSE   & 12th IEEE International Conference On Big Data Science And Engineering\\
ICCCS       & 2019 4th International Conference on Computing, Communications and Security \\
ATS         & 2019 IEEE 28th Asian Test Symposium \\
MSR         & 2019 IEEE/ACM 16th International Conference on Mining Software Repositories \\
ICOIN       & 2019 International Conference on Information Networking \\
ISVLSI      & 2020 IEEE Computer Society Annual Symposium on VLSI \\
ICAC        & 2021 26th International Conference on Automation and Computing \\
INCET       & 2021 2nd International Conference for Emerging  Technology \\
ICACCS      & 2021 7th International Conference on Advanced Computing and Communication Systems \\
Big Data    & 2021 IEEE International Conference on Big Data \\
ASIANCON    & 2022 2nd Asian Conference on Innovation in Technology \\
NCCC        & 2022 Fifth National Conference of Saudi Computers Colleges \\
CCNC        & 2022 IEEE 19th Annual Consumer Communications \& Networking Conference \\
TrustCom    & 2022 IEEE International Conference on Trust, Security and Privacy in Computing and Communications \\
DISCOVER    & 2022 International Conference on Distributed Computing, VLSI, Electrical Circuits and Robotics \\
ICIMCIS     & 2022 International Conference on Informatics, Multimedia, Cyber and Information System \\
MLCSS       & 2022 International Conference on Machine Learning, Computer Systems and Security \\
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \caption{Tabela de Critérios de Inclusão e Exclusão}
\begin{tblr}{colspec  = {Q[l, wd=0.2\linewidth] X[l]},
             row{odd} = {bg=gray!10},
             row{1}   = {font=\bfseries}
             }
Critérios de Inclusão
        &   \\
IC1     & O artigo foi publicado entre 2018-2022 \\
IC2     & O artigo está no contexto de Vírus de computador e propõe uma abordagem para análise e detecção do vírus\\
\textbf{Critérios de Exclusão}
        &   \\
EC1     & O artigo não foi publicado em uma conferência, periódico ou revista listados na Tabela 1 e 2 \\
EC2     & O manuscrito é um livro ou artigo de acesso antecipado\\
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\lipsum[66]   % <--- dummy text filler
\end{document}
```

[image]

As You can see, I instead your table code, which cause that tables  protrude right text block border, use `tabularrray` package with `X[l]` for the second table column. By it is also simplified coloring of rows.

Since context of appearing of your tables is unknown (are they alone?), you may use `float` package and write just this two tables as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H]
\caption{Conferências, revistas e periódicos da IEEE de interesse}
\begin{tblr}{colspec  = {Q[l, wd=0.2\linewidth] X[l]},
             row{odd} = {bg=gray!10},
             row{1}   = {font=\bfseries}
             }
Acrônimos   &   Nome completo       \\
TrustCom    & 2018 17th IEEE International Conference On Trust, Security And Privacy In Computing And Communications \\
BigDataSE   & 12th IEEE International Conference On Big Data Science And Engineering\\
ICCCS       & 2019 4th International Conference on Computing, Communications and Security \\
ATS         & 2019 IEEE 28th Asian Test Symposium \\
MSR         & 2019 IEEE/ACM 16th International Conference on Mining Software Repositories \\
ICOIN       & 2019 International Conference on Information Networking \\
ISVLSI      & 2020 IEEE Computer Society Annual Symposium on VLSI \\
ICAC        & 2021 26th International Conference on Automation and Computing \\
INCET       & 2021 2nd International Conference for Emerging  Technology \\
ICACCS      & 2021 7th International Conference on Advanced Computing and Communication Systems \\
Big Data    & 2021 IEEE International Conference on Big Data \\
ASIANCON    & 2022 2nd Asian Conference on Innovation in Technology \\
NCCC        & 2022 Fifth National Conference of Saudi Computers Colleges \\
CCNC        & 2022 IEEE 19th Annual Consumer Communications \& Networking Conference \\
TrustCom    & 2022 IEEE International Conference on Trust, Security and Privacy in Computing and Communications \\
DISCOVER    & 2022 International Conference on Distributed Computing, VLSI, Electrical Circuits and Robotics \\
ICIMCIS     & 2022 International Conference on Informatics, Multimedia, Cyber and Information System \\
MLCSS       & 2022 International Conference on Machine Learning, Computer Systems and Security \\
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
  \caption{Tabela de Critérios de Inclusão e Exclusão}
\begin{tblr}{colspec  = {Q[l, wd=0.2\linewidth] X[l]},
             row{odd} = {bg=gray!10},
             row{1}   = {font=\bfseries}
             }
Critérios de Inclusão
        &   \\
IC1     & O artigo foi publicado entre 2018-2022 \\
IC2     & O artigo está no contexto de Vírus de computador e propõe uma abordagem para análise e detecção do vírus\\
\textbf{Critérios de Exclusão}
        &   \\
EC1     & O artigo não foi publicado em uma conferência, periódico ou revista listados na Tabela 1 e 2 \\
EC2     & O manuscrito é um livro ou artigo de acesso antecipado\\
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot